# I can’t build in the apk file it gives an error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk

I can’t build in the apk file, it gives an error, help fix it.

I will show you the error and screenshots

> Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct. See the Console for more details. 
>   C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk-14.0.1\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/Sanchek19/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar"
>
> stderr[
>       Error:Invalid command android
>   ]
>   stdout[
>   ]
>   exit code: 64

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emlDz.png)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like exactly the same issue described here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1343613/need-help-asap-building-apk-file-error-commandinvo.html

I was also able to encounter this error in the past - using older Android Build Tools should help, just like the described `25.2.5`. Google deprecated the `android` command in meantime, so that it returnes 64 result code.

Out of curiosity, what is your Unity version?